# getting error when making a post request in ionic angular

Tags: angular, tomcat, jax-rs, ionic3

i am very new to ionic3 and jaxrs so guide me in correct way to learn

```
    @POST
    @Path("example1")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<DairyDTO> getTodaydairyForParents(EmployeeDTO employee) {
        empList = employeeDAO.getRecords(employee.getname());


    return empList ;    
}
```

This is working fine in postman

but when i made post request

```
let employee = new URLSearchParams();
employee.set('name', "Ram");

this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/sms/webapi/test/example1', employee, {
            headers: headers
        }).map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => {
        // we've got back the raw data, now generate the core schedule data
        // and save the data for later reference
        this.data = data;
        resolve(this.data);
      });

i am getting errors
```

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:8080/restexample/webapi/test/example1. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin localhost:8100`' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

Filters used in tomcat

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: You need to [configure the CorsFilter with some init-params](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter) telling it what origins you want to allow.

Comment: @peeskillet  i have configure the Apache CorsFilter in tomcat

Comment: add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" to your filter

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to communicate to http://localhost:8080/ using XMLHttpRequest from localhost:8100 which is not allowed by default.
Your server should trust to localhost:8100 by adding it to the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8100
```

You should configure the Apache CorsFilter parameters according to the access policy you need.

Comment: i have configure the Apache CorsFilter in tomcat

Comment: No, its init parameters are not configured. Look at [this](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter/Initialisation_parameters) sample.